# Number comparison issue in Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to compare two numbers in a batch file.  Here is my code:

```
set filedate=201710191858
set newestdate=201710131108
if %filedate% gtr %newestdate% (
  echo bingo
)
```

Why is bingo not written here?

Comment: batch is limited to 31-bit values. Your dates exceed 31-bit capacity. If you "quote" each side, the comparison should proceed as expected (assuming your values are of the same length)

Comment: To get the maximum numeric value (2147483647), enter `set /A 0x7FFFFFFF` at the command prompt.